# Why not simple function calls instead of xml tags for React components?

Tags: reactjs

I'm wondering why React uses xml tags while it's just some simple function calls. Is it just for convenient for frontend developers migrating from plain html to React?
Consider this:

```
return <Component x={this.props.x} y={() => alert(123)}>
    <AnotherCompoent x={this.state.x} y='123'/>
    <hr style={borderColor: 'red'}/>
</Component>;
```

It can be written with function calls like this:

```
return Component(
    {x: this.props.x, y: () => alert(123)},
    [
        AnotherComponent({x: this.state.x, y: '123'}),
        hr({style: {borderColor: 'red'}}),
    ],
);
```

It seems much more familiar for all developers (except those who has html background) as function calls, dicts and lists are familiar concepts for all languages. It doesn't make all editors to waste time to support a new syntax. It's "easier to reason about" (the term they love).

### Edit

Is it possible to use current react library as function calls?

### Edit 2

Actually using JSX introduces more trouble than just supporting it in all editors. Just remember all the curly braces you put in your JSX to embed JS in. While in pure JS you just write your code.

Comment: It's not necessary to use an array in your "function" example, just pass each child as separate arguments.

Comment: @TomFenech yeah, that'd be even easier.

Comment: The first part of your "question" sounds a bit like a rant, you seem to have already answered the question in your first edit, and then your second edit is just more rant. As it stands, I'm not really sure what you're asking.

Comment: @TomFenech The title of my post initiates with `Why`. The question is obvious: "Why React uses a new syntax instead of using pure JS?" I wrote my reasons that I think a new syntax is not required but it doesn't mean I answered my own question. I still think there's possibility that someone comes and gives a good answer why React introduced a new syntax. I'm not still sure they had no valid reasons. The question "Is it possible to use current react library as function calls" is strongly bound branch of main question.

Comment: ... I'm still wondering if I can call React components as in the second code snippet in the question. Maybe there's a library that provides `h`, `div`, etc so that I don't need to call `createElement` for native html tags.

Comment: You can use the factories `DOM.div()`. Try it!

Comment: Great, thanks. It answers the branched question.

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of preference really, and it's called JSX and not XML. You can use React without JSX as documented in [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-without-jsx.html). The reason why I use JSX is because it is declarative, thus making it easier to describe how the UI should look like. I can't imagine how one would manage without JSX for a component that contains many deeply nested components.

Comment: I know it's JSX, but JSX is a combination of XML and JS, so the tag syntax is XML. About "I can't imagine how one..." I don't see any difference, JSX is a syntax that adds "nothing" look at the example above, even indentation is the same, it ALMOST just replaces `(` in function call with `<`, `[` in second parameter (for children) with `>` and `)` in function call with `</...>` or `/>`. So it doesn't even change the look and yet it made so much work for editors to support it. And introducing a new syntax for each library doesn't seem to be a good idea.

Comment: This is just my preference and I have answered your question so as to whether you can call react as a function call. What works on me may not work on you or other people. Using JSX does introduce a lot of overhead in the processing stage, but people do it because it makes it more intuitive for a lot of people when developing UI.

Comment: I guess people do it because React developers advertised it this way. There's absolutely no benefit. You can't replace `.` with `,` in `django.models` just cause it MAY look better in a python library. It's an antipattern. When you're developing a library, develop a library, don't create a new syntax for every library you build.

Comment: Using JSX is not a requirement. If you don't like it, don't use it. React can still work either way.

Comment: Is there a library that provides `div`, `span`, etc so that I don't have to call `React.createElement` for native html tags?

Answer (score 1):

The style of writing that you are comparing with XML is `JSX`, its an alternative for using the pure `Javascript` by creating elements everytime by making use of function `React.createElement()` which though possible makes your component very complex for nested elements. `JSX` allows you to write `HTML style` coding in `Javascript` which is then transpiled into pure Javascrip[t code through `babel` for instance.

Comment: No need for `React.createElement`, just use factories.

Comment: @TomFenech, I understand, but even if you do that, don't you think its much more easier and readable if you write in JSX

Comment: I know how it works, I've written more than 50k code of jsx in my last 2 projects. But I think they added a new syntax for no reason. I think they were just influenced by the impression that the library they're creating is so important that it needs a new syntax. Which i'm sure is an antipattern to create a new syntax for every new library you build considering they could implement it with pure js syntax perfectly.

Comment: Not really, no! I don't think that `MyComponent({ prop1, prop2 }, Child())` is worse than `<MyComponent prop1={prop1} prop2={prop2}><Child /></MyComponent>`.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I don't get it why you think it's easier in JSX than pure JS. Just look at the above example. They're just the same if you wanna "reason about them".

Comment: I would say its a matter of perspective, I find it convenient since it very similar to HTML